# itemize: How to change horizontal spacing to subitems in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

Bugged me for some time: how to change the space pointed out below?

```
* abc
* cde
     > fgh
 ^^^^
 this
```

Answer (score 2):

I added into my .sty file the following

```
\newlength{\myitem}
\setlength{\myitem}{\widthof{\small\raise1.0pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}+\labelsep}

\setlength{\leftmargini}{\myitem }
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{\myitem }
\setlength{\leftmarginiii}{\myitem}
```

found here: [Latex Beamer class](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.beamer.general/2583)